# What does "(?x::" mean in a Boost regex replacement, where "x" is a number?

Tags: regex, boost, sublimetext2

This is a Perl-style Regular Expression found in one of the snippet files in the Ruby package of Sublime Text 2:

```
/(?:\A|_)([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?:\.rb)?/(?2::\u$1)/g
```

I know it converts a file name like "some_class.rb" into "SomeClass", but I can't figure out what this part does: `(?2::`. Sublime Text 2 uses boost for its Regular Expressions, so I checked the documentation for [Boost-Extended Format String Syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html), and I found that boost supports conditionals in the format string (f.inst. `(?2(foo):(bar))`) but you'll never need two colons for that. Additionally, `?2` would point to the *second* sub-expression, but the expression above only ever matches one sub-expression. For those reasons, I don't think this is a conditional expression.

Thanks for any enlightening answers.

Comment: Maybe it's just working by accident? Maybe the first `:` is the `true` part, the second `:` delimits the `false` part. But since `2` isn't part of the expression, the conditional can never use the `true` part and hence it just always uses `\u$1` (which is in agreement with the results you see).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, the `(?2::\u$1)` on the replacement side of `///g` is *not* Perl. It's Boost's own extension

- see [[Search and Replace Format String Syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format.html) > [Boost-Extended Format String Syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html)] as mentioned by OP.

Referring to said document, it is saith,

> The character '?' begins a conditional expression, the general form is:
>
> `?Ntrue-expression:false-expression`
>
> where N is decimal digit.
>
> If sub-expression N was matched, then true-expression is evaluated and sent to output, otherwise false-expression is evaluated and sent to output.

Based on this, let's analyze the mysterious `(?2::\u$1)`

1. `?2` is *always* false, because there is *no* 2nd capturing group.
2. the first `:` is a "special character" in `true-expression` which means empty string

   - if we assume that `true-expression` cannot be left empty, the first `:` is *not* interpreted as the separator between the true- and false-expression (for the gory/juicy details, please read **Appendix D**).
   - in fact, we can put whatever we want as `true-expression` (as long as there is no `:` somewhere in the middle) since `?2` never evaluates to true.
3. `\u$1` is the `false-expression`.

Putting two and two together, I'm going to go out on a limb and say

```
/(?:\A|_)([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?:\.rb)?/(?2::\u$1)/g
```

is but an obfuscated way of doing this:

```
/(?:\A|_)([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?:\.rb)?/\u$1/g
```

---

### Appendix D: Experimentation with snippet in Sublime Text 2

So I defined a Sublime Text 2 snippet with this content

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
snakecase: ${1:hello_world}
camelcase: ${1/(?:\A|_)([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?:\.rb)?/(?2::\u$1)/g}
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>convert</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

and played around with different expressions for the right side of substitution.

Given the input `hello_world`

1. if right side is `(?2::\u$1)`, returns `HelloWorld`
2. if right side is `(?2:\u$1)`, returns `HW`
3. if right side is `(?2:$1)`, returns nothing
4. if right side is `(?2:::\u$1)`, returns `:Hello:World`
5. if right side is `(?1:\u$1)`, returns `HelloWorld`
6. if right side is `(?1::\u$1)`, returns `HW`
7. if right side is `(?1::$1)`, returns nothing
8. if right side is `(?1:::\u$1)` returns `HW`
9. if right side is `(?1:::$1)` returns nothing
10. if right side is `\u$1`, returns `HelloWorld`

Some tentative conclusions based on this (assuming that cases 2, 6, 8 are anomalies<sup>†</sup>)

- if only a single colon (`:`) follows the digit, it is ignored (i.e. it is not interpreted as the separator between true- and false-expression).
- if 2 colons (`::`) follow the digit, the `true-expression` is an empty string (2nd `:` is the separator)
- if 3 colons (`:::`) follow the digit, the `true-expression` is an empty string, and the `false-expression` starts with a literal colon (2nd `:` is the separator)
- comparing cases 1 and 10, my conclusion on the equivalence of `(?2::\u$1)` and `\u$1` still stands.

<sup>†</sup> I said anomalies because `\u$1` behaves so differently compared to `$1` (everything except the first character of captured substring disappears)

Comment: It seems more likely that the `if` part is simply parsed greedily (so that the last `:` marks the boundary between `true` and `false`), than that the `if` part can not be empty, but contain only a single `:`. But someone would have to do a few tests to figure this out.

Comment: In fact, I just typed this into notepad++ (which uses boost as of version 6), and it's indeed the first colon that separates true and false - hence there is a literal `:` included in the replacement, and shawnhcorey has been right all along.

Comment: @m.buettner, snippet in Sublime Text proved otherwise, i.e. no `:` is inserted in replacement

Comment: Interesting. Well, SublimeText's behavior is obviously what's relevant to the question, but interestingly I get completely different results in Notepad++. I wonder whether it's due to different versions of boost or something. If someone has the time, it might be interesting to test this directly in boost. And with SublimeText I come to the same conclusion: it uses `(?n:true:false)`, but is buggy if a `\u` is in the unused part.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there's a colon in the replacement string, like `:\u$1` is the replacement string.

Comment: I ran some tests with Notepad++ (which uses boost) and it seems you're right.